# golang/pq pq: operator does not exist: bigint = text

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

```
query := "WITH b(ColA, ColB) AS (VALUES ($1,$2)) UPDATE schema_name.table_name AS a SET ColC = b.ColB FROM b WHERE a.ColA = b.ColA AND a.ColB = b.ColB"
res, err := db.Exec(query, 1, 1)
```

The above code fails with the following error:

```
pq: operator does not exist: bigint = text
```

"ColC" is of type BIGINT.

From my investigation, the driver is inserting the values as text instead of ints.

issue: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/582

Comment: b.ColA and b.ColB are bigint?

Comment: Did you try adding explicit type casts? e.g. `query := "WITH b(ColA, ColB) AS (VALUES ($1::bigint,$2::bigint)) UPDATE schema_name.table_name AS a SET ColC = b.ColB FROM b WHERE a.ColA = b.ColA AND a.ColB = b.ColB"
res, err := db.Exec(query, 1, 1)`

Comment: Yes explicit casting works but defeat the purpose of the driver inferring the type of the argument and writing to DB accordingly

Comment: @VaoTsun b is a temp table built with the injected values which are ints.

Comment: just to be sure, populate the result of `select pg_typeof(b.ColA),pg_typeof(b.ColB) from b`

Comment: @VaoTsun b is not a concrete table. It is a temp table built as part of the query mentioned in the question.

Comment: `WITH b(ColA, ColB) AS (VALUES ($1,$2)) select pg_typeof(b.ColA),pg_typeof(b.ColB) from b` please run it with same prepared values as you have error with

Comment: @Abhishek You were using this driver for explicit type inferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be the postgres behavior and not the driver.
I had to use explicit casts to get my queries to work.